# make a column in sybase default to the current date/time of row insertion

Tags: date, default, sybase

I have a sybase 15 DB and for one of my tables, I want to make a column default to the current date/time of the row insert. Is this possible?

In a sybase text, the following is said:

```
ALTER TABLE sales_order
MODIFY order_date DEFAULT CURRENT DATE
```

On my DB this doesn't do anything, as `CURRENT DATE` is not recognized.

Answer (score 9):

using `getDate()` is a valid solution, you must have had a syntax error. Try it like this:

```
create table test_tbl (
     date_data DATETIME default getDate() NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: this fails to satisfy the "current date/time of the row insert". It will update the date when the row is modified as documented [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00170.1540/doc/html/san1288042837002.html) for Sybase IQ: "The value is updated with the current date and time whenever the row is updated."

Comment: It's worth noting that (unlike Sql Server) the order of the parts of the column specification is important: "date_data DATETIME default getDate() NOT NULL" is valid; while "date_data DATETIME NOT NULL default getDate()" is not.

Comment: I tried the same, date is getting updated only on insert but not during update. Any idea why? CREATE TABLE items 
   (
      name VARCHAR(90),
      dt DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
      price NUMERIC(7,2)
   );

Answer (score 3):

Try using getDate() instead

Comment: it says I need a Constant, constant expression, or variable after default.

Comment: That's surprising, I'm pretty sure I used it (for a table definition), like written here http://vista.intersystems.com/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=RSQL_getdate  Unless you are not using Sybase ASE?

Answer (score 2):

... `DEFAULT GETDATE()` is correct.  the case is irrelevant; mixed case may indicate a Java method, but it is a straight TSQL Function.  Please post the exact error msg if you want further assistance.

Also, the ALTER TABLE method sets the Default for *future* INSERTS; if you want the existing data changed, you need to UPDATE (good for small tables) or unload/reload the table (demanded for the large).

Watch the NULL/NOT NULL: you do not want to change that without understanding.  Again, the existing/future issue needs address.  NOT NULL prevents NULL being explicitly passed as an INSERT VALUE.

Comment: But how do you get it to not update the date on updates like it does with the "current" keyword?

Answer (score 1):

CURRENT_DATE is a SQL standard that isn't universally adopted. 
As noted elsewhere the getdate() T-SQL function should be used instead.